# Steps to integrate fabricjs into existing application

Tags: fabricjs

There exists legacy application having 3 canvas. First canvas to display objects which is stored in container, second canvas when object is selected and third one when object is moved or added for editing. I want to use the text and image feature of fabricJS into my existing application. While creating fabricJS canvas, i provided editing canvas object then all the mouse events bind to the editing canvas stopped working. So does there exists way to use fabricJS into existing application only for using the text and image feature of fabricJS.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to dynamically assign a `z-index` value to a canvas layer to expose or hide the layer to mouse events.

For the layers that you want to hide mouse events from, set `z-index` value to `-1`.  For the layer that you want to expose to mouse events, set `z-index` value to `1`.

```
  var textLayer = document.getElementById("text-layer");
  textLayer.style["z-index"] = 1;
```